# How to use sed to delete log file line that are older than 30 days old

Tags: bash, shell

I have a log file in below format and I want to delete the lines older than 30 days to clean up the disk space. I cannot empty the file due to compliance requirement. I have used below sed format but its not working. Please suggest how this can be achieved using sed or any other option.

I tried this:

```
sed -i "s@^[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9]@$(date -d "-30 days" +"%m/%d/%Y")@g" "$file"
```

logfile:

```
12/31/2022 03:00:49 ANS1228E Sending of object '/xxxxxe/xxx' failed.
12/31/2022 03:00:49 ANS0326E This node has exceeded its maximum number of mount points.
12/31/2022 03:00:49 ANS1228E Sending of object '/xxxxx/XXX/product' failed.
12/31/2022 03:00:49 ANS0326E This node has exceeded its maximum number of mount points.
12/31/2022 03:00:49 ANS1228E Sending of object '/XXX/XXX/product/XXXXXXX'
```

Comment: Guess `logrotate` is a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`sed -i 's@'"$(date -d "-46 days" +"%m/%d/%Y")".*'@@g' "$file"`

Comment: Thank you for your response. This has worked, but its leaving the empty line after clearing the line. need another sed command to delete the blank lines

Comment: You can use `sed -i '/^$/d' "$file"` to delete all the empty lines..

Comment: Thanks, its working perfectly now..put both sed commands in for loop to complete the script.